# Run python script without type pythonat the front

Tags: python

Usually I run python script python myscript.py,

I want to run script directly without type python,

I already Add shebang: #!/usr/bin/env python at the top of my script.

And then give the file permission to execute by: chmod +x SleepCalc.py

but it still tell me "Command not found"

Is anything I need to change in cshell?or anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running it from the same folder using `./SleepCalc.py` command?

`SleepCalc.py`only will not work.